# Plotting a graph of the top 15 highest values

Tags: pandas, dataframe, plot

I am working on a dataset which shows the budget spent on movies. I want make a plot which contains the top 15 highest budget movies.

```
#sort the 'budget' column in decending order and store it in the new dataframe.
info = pd.DataFrame(dp['budget'].sort_values(ascending = False))
info['original_title'] = dp['original_title']
data = list(map(str,(info['original_title'])))

#extract the top 10 budget movies data from the list and dataframe.
x = list(data[:10])
y = list(info['budget'][:10])
```

This was the ouput i got

```
C:\Users\Phillip\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_7692\1681814737.py:2: FutureWarning: The behavior of `series[i:j]` with an integer-dtype index is deprecated. In a future version, this will be treated as *label-based* indexing, consistent with e.g. `series[i]` lookups. To retain the old behavior, use `series.iloc[i:j]`. To get the future behavior, use `series.loc[i:j]`.
  y = list(info['budget'][:5])
```

I'm new to the data analysis scene so i'm confused on how else to go about the problem

Comment: dataframes have nlargest(): Try something like `dp.nlargest(n=15, columns="budget")`. Docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html

Answer (score 0):

A simple example using a movie dataset I found online:

```
import pandas as pd

url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/erajabi/Python_examples/master/movie_sample_dataset.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(url)

# Bar plot of 15 highest budgets:
df.nlargest(n=15, columns="budget").plot.bar(x="movie_title", y="budget")
```

You can customize your plot in various ways by adding arguments to the `.bar(...)` call.

[image: Bar plot]